# Problems with ActionBar. How to fix it?

Tags: android, android-actionbar, genymotion

[image: Screenshot]

ActionBar menu does not appear on android 4.2.2

Comment: Edit your question with your code!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Samsung Galaxy S3 you're simulating has a physical menu button, seen here on the bottom left:

[image: samsung phone]

For devices with such a button (mostly older Android phones), the overflow menu with the three dots is not needed and therefore hidden. Instead, you bring up the menu by pressing the menu key.

Your simulator should also have a menu button.